# Expression(string: ) not parsing correct result in DDMathParser

Tags: ddmathparser

```
expressions[2] = "$x**3/3+$x*$z**2+2*($x**2-$z**2)"

let mathParserExpression2 = try Expression(string: expressions[2])
```

results in $x ** 3.0 ÷ 3.0 + $x * $z ** 2.0 + 2.0 * $x ** 2.0 − $z ** 2.0

What to do?

Even

```
expressions[2] = "$x**3/3+$x*$z**2+2($x**2-$z**2)"
```

produces same effect. Checked this in your Tests and fails to create required expression.

Answer (score 0):

Checked using Demo app with the expression and I get correct results. Didn't get the 3D shape I expected, so troubleshooting initially led me astray.